# Changing External Browser in Eclipse [Linux, GWT, Tomcat6]

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, web-applications, tomcat6

Upon attempting to deploy my GWT application, Eclipse constantly deploys to Aurora (bleeding-edge Firefox build - located in /usr/bin/firefox). Are there programmatic steps to follow, or do I need to modify external configuration files to change the web browser?

**Steps taken:**

Window -> General -> Web Browser:

[New External Browser]

1. Name: Google Chrome
2. Location: /usr/bin/google-chrome
3. Parameters:

Window -> Web Browser -> Google Chrome[x]

Any suggestions? Is there some kind of persistent variable, or configuration file that I've looked over?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can right-click the deployment line to get other browser options:

[image]

That said, I've taken to just opening the browser I want first and typing the address in by hand - the browsers know me well enough to auto-complete the whole thing at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a web browser by going to Window > Preferences > General > Web Browser

If you can see desired web browser then select it.
In my case running on Ubuntu 22.04 and Eclipse 2022-09, I cannot see any browser

Click on New button, you will see a pop up form.
add your Browser Name, now you need location

go to terminal type `whereis firefox` firefox. In my case, I got result as `snap/bin/firefox`

type the same in location and hit ok button.

Select the browser and Start the server it should run on the desired browser.

Note: sometimes after server startup firefox may not be launched. In such case manually launch and close and then start the server